# Apply Follow Path animation to an object?

Tags: animation, objects, constraints

I have an object with it's own skeleton that is parented to an Axis that follows a curved path using the Follow Path constraint. I want to apply this animation to the object so it can be independent of the curve and the axis. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object menu > Animation > Bake Action
This should, as the UI says, bake all selected objects location/scale/rotation animation to an action. Make sure to select visual keying or the curved follow path trajectory won't be baked to the object that has the constraint or any object parented to the constrained object.

Comment: This is partly the answer, but I figured it out myself. I followed a tutorial that used an empty Axis with the Follow Path constraint as a parent to the object, when I realized I could just give the constraint to the object's root bone and skip all the hassle of moving animations from the axis to the object.